# sslstream "The BeginWrite method cannot be called when another write operation is pending"

Tags: c#, sslstream

I am having a bit of trouble getting the sslstream to work with sending multiple message after each other.

The way i call my client to send data

```
client.Send(objectOne);
client.Send(objectTwo);
```

the error message i receive is:

```
The BeginWrite method cannot be called when another write operation is pending
```

i have tried different solutions to get this to work, but none gets the it to work.

The base function uses await, and that function gets called

```
// client send
public void Send(object data)
{
    byte[] sendData = SerializationHelper.Serialize(data);
    base.Send(sendData);
}
// base send
protected async void Send(byte[] data)
{
    await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

Base function returns a task, and uses await in the client method

```
// client send
public async void Send(object data)
{
    byte[] sendData = SerializationHelper.Serialize(data);
    await base.Send(sendData);
}
// base send
protected async Task Send(byte[] data)
{
    await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

i still receive the same error, anyone have any idea to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the task parallel library yet, but... By making `Send` an `async` method, you begin the send operation but do not wait for it to complete. You need to wait for `Send` to complete. One way to do this is to run it synchronously:

```
client.Send(objectOne).RunSynchronously();
client.Send(objectTwo).RunSynchronously();
```

Instead, you could also do this at the client level like this:

```
// client send
public void Send(object data)
{
    byte[] sendData = SerializationHelper.Serialize(data);
    base.Send(sendData).RunSynchronously();
}
// base send
protected async void Send(byte[] data)
{
    await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

Comment: tried with editing in the client like in the last code your wrote and got this error now "RunSynchronously may not be called on a task not bound to a delegate, such as the task returned from an asynchronous method." any ideas?